# Arduino ESP8266 Ticker interrupted by DallasTemperature/OneWire?

Tags: esp8266

I have been using the Ticker to blink a led successfully.
However, now I am fetching temperature from a DS18B20 in the main loop (which is using the OneWire library) and the blink is now erratic.

Is the Ticker suspended by the DallasTemperature/OneWire library?

It this suspending interrupts or something?

Maybe using the same interrupt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ticker does not interrupt your code. It is a OS-timer and will call your function once the time is elapsed.

The Tiker callback can be interrupted by a "real" interrupt or another Task with higher priority and does not provide any reliability - it will just be called.

A solution (not the best) would be to disable manually all interrupts, if you can't solve it in another way.

If you just want a blinking led, you should use a Timer interrupt as your callback is short and fast. Maybe with the `ICACHE_RAM_ATTR` attribute.

Comment: OS-timer means it's get called after the loop() or during a yield() is that correct?

Comment: @HixField sorry, I didn't wrote it correctly. It is called during the loop. It will "interrupt" the loop, but not another interrupt and not an important operation (like an access to the SPIFFS). It will for example executed once the SPIFFS-transaction is over or once the SPI/OneWire-interrupt is over. (A HW-Timer can interrupt also a SPIFFS-access).

Comment: Hmm ok. It is strange though because I just changed my DS18B20 implementation to a non blocking one (in the loop) and now everything is working fine. I checked the DS18B20 lib and the only thing it does to "block" was a while(...) {} (without any yield). I do have the impression that the ticker can be inrerrupted by blocking functions...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a problem using libraries with sensor DS18B20 in ticker. If I request the temperature through millis(), then everything is fine. When I request the temperature in the ticker, I get "Panic core_esp8266_main.cpp:137 __yield". Unfortunately I can't explain it.

Comment: This doesn't really provide an answer to the question. To ask another question, just click [Ask Question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) above. If you wish, include a link to this question to help provide context.

Comment: You're right: this is not an answer, just more information. I made a mistake: I posted this text in the wrong place. Should have been in the comments.